# What do I get rid of to install Ubuntu when I have 4 primary partitions?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am very new to Ubuntu and Linux in general, so any advice is appreciated. I am following the "Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu in Perfect Harmony" tutorial on Lifehacker to do exactly that. [This](http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony) is the link. I am at the step of partitioning my system, I already have windows installed but i am in the Ubuntu Live. When i go into the GParted Partition Editor and try and select "new" I get this message:

> It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions.
>
> If you want more partitions you should first create an extended
>   partition. Such a partition can contain other partitions. Because an
>   extended partition is also a primary partition it might be necessary
>   to remove a primary partition first

Thats all!

Wow! Ubuntu's community is amazing, i was expecting at least a day wait for an answer. Anyways, here is the picture:

[image]

Also, i forgot to tell you, but i am on a laptop for this project, if that changes anything.

thanks for all of you help so far!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You will need to get rid of one partition, and convert it into an extended partition, and then create as many logical partitions as you want under it. What does your GParted show? What are the partitions? You probably have the very important `sda1`, that's about 100MB! Then you have `sda2`, which is your Windows partition, then maybe `sda3` which is your D: drive, then `sda4` which is probably your recovery drive, or HP_TOOLS if your laptop is HP branded. Take a screenshot of GParted. Upload it to http://imgur.com/, and give us the link to it.

Comment: Yes, the Linux community is truly awesome! Also, just an advice, you should comment back here when you edit your question, because otherwise we (the people that commented) will not get notified of your edit. Back to your question: in my opinion, from the screenshot, the easiest way for you is to get rid of the "Data" partition, since you've only used 12 GBs of it.

Comment: Here are the steps that will be involved: Copy everything in the Data partition to your OS_Install. Delete the Data partition. Create extended partition. Recreate a "Data" partition. Proceed with installing Ubuntu in the remaining space. When everything is done, you'll copy back whatever was in your old Data partition to the new one. Is this a possible method for you? Shall I proceed with answering the question with detailed steps? If yes, I'm actually going to advice you to ditch that Lifehacker tutorial, it's ancient! Also, I hope you're not trying to install Ubuntu 9.10, it's also ancient!

Comment: Okay! Lifehacker ditched, I'm trying to install 13.04 so i am on the right track. The instructions you have explained already seem quite straightforward, though i am a little worried of messing something big up.Detailed instructions would be great! Edit: I just opened up GParted and next to my sda 3 there is a exclamation mark with a red bubble around it... should i be worried? Thanks again

Comment: Right click on `sda3` > Information, it'll give you some information about what's wrong. What happened from the time your posted the screenshot to now? I'd advice you boot into Windows, and let it "check disks" if it asks, and then do a proper, normal shut down using the Shut down option. I'll post an answer in a bit.

Comment: **I disagree that this question should be marked as duplicate. Each Win laptop is different as to which primary partition can be deleted or made logical. Please list your laptop model and how your Win partitions are marked. Did it come with these partitions or you created any of them?**

Answer (score 0):

> ***Disclaimer:** always take a current backup of your hard disk prior to playing around with partitions.*
>
> ***Note1:** GParted "records" the actions that we're doing, so it's not actually creating or deleting any partitions until we hit **Apply**. So, if you mess up before applying, just undo or close and reopen GParted.*
>
> ***Note2:** your screenshot shows a low battery. Ensure that your laptop is plugged into a power source and charging.*

1. Copy all the contents of the **Data** partition to your C drive, or to an external storage device, because we're going to delete it. You can do this normally in Windows, or you can do this in Live Ubuntu. In Live Ubuntu, if you move your mouse to the bottom of the Launcher on the left, you'll find a couple of hard disk icons. Clicking them will mount and open up the partitions.
2. In Live Ubuntu, open up GParted. Right click and "Unmount" the partitions if you opened them up (if you followed the previous step).
3. Right click on `sda4` > **Delete**.
4. Right click on the now large `unallocated` > **New**:

   - Create as: **Extended Partition**
   - Click **Add**.
5. Right click on the new `unallocated` (which is nested under "New Partition") > **New**:

   - Create as: **Logical Partition** *(you shouldn't be able to change it anyways.)*
   - File system: **ntfs**
   - Label: **Data**
   - Free space preceding: `0`
   - New size: `181524`

     - This is 177 GB. You can of course, change it to however big you want your new Data partition to be.
   - When you click away, the Free space following should fill up automatically.
   - Click **Add**.

   It should now look like this:

   ```
   sda1
   sda2
   sda3
   New Partition
         New Partition (Data)       177.27 GB
         unallocated                119 GB
   ```
6. Take a look at your partitions. Cross your fingers. Pray. Take another look. If you're satisfied, click the green check mark in GParted to apply. This **shouldn't** take too long, maybe 10 minutes maximum...probably take a few seconds =/.
7. At this point, you can boot back into Windows and copy back your Data stuff, or continue with installing Ubuntu since you're already in Live Ubuntu.

Now, you have an unallocated space that can be used to create new partitions and install Ubuntu.

There are several ways from here to install Ubuntu. I would highly advise this:

1. Click on the **Install Ubuntu to Hard Disk** icon in the Launcher on the left (second icon from top).
2. When presented with options, choose **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7**. This will basically take care of everything. It will detect the free, unallocated space, and install itself there, along with creating an essential partition called [swap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq). It will not touch your other Windows partitions. The only thing that can go wrong here is bootloader stuff, where you might not get a screen to "choose" which OS, and it just boots into Ubuntu or Windows. This can be fixed using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but I doubt that it'll get to this point.
3. When it's done, reboot your computer (and don't forget to remove your USB/CD so that you don't boot into Live Ubuntu), and you should be presented with options to choose your OS. At this point, I like to first boot into Windows to make sure that it boots successfully. When it does, shutdown and boot into Ubuntu...and enjoy.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Don't forget to [mark one of the answers as your accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate that this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [FixParts program](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) to convert your current `/dev/sda4` partition from primary to logical, which will automatically create a containing extended partition in the process. You might then need to reboot and use GParted to resize the extended partition to cover all the disk's free space so that the Ubuntu installer can use it. This procedure is likely to be much less of a hassle than what Alaa has outlined. I do agree with his recommendation to back up your data, though -- *any* partition manipulation is inherently at least a little risky and can result in massive data loss. Although that risk is low, the cost of recovery can be very high, so having a backup is a worthwhile precaution.

Answer (score -2):

The ubuntu dualboot will detect the unallocated space and install ubuntu on that part.

If you are using windows 7 there is a partition tool (search for it in the startbutton meny) where you can handle your partitions and resize them.

Comment: No, Ubuntu will not be able to use the unallocated space because he has 4 primary partitions. It'll spit out an error along the lines of "cannot create another partition" or something like that, that is, **if** it spits out an error.